# How to draw a series of connected lines in Libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm using polygon on shape renderer and the problem is that the user should be able to add vertex whenever they want, basically the vertices are not set by me but by the user. What I did is whenever the user add a point, I add them to an arrayList.

```
ArrayList<Float> v = new ArrayList<Float>();
public void ontouch(screenX, screenY){
      v.add(screenX);
      v.add(screenY)
}
```

And then I have this problem when I try to render a polygon on a shapeRenderer

```
for(int i = 0; i < v.size; i++){
    float[] vertices = new float[v.size()]
    vertices[i - 1] = v.get(i - 1);
    vertices[i] = v.get(i);
}
sr.polygon(v);
```

But I just get errors.

I am trying to achieve something like this, if you know a different way of doing this then that would be really helpful. By the way I'm also using box2d and this does not need to have collision it's just for the user visual.[image]

Answer (score 2):

The way I would personally do it is by having an `LinkedList` with `Vector2` objects. `Vector2` objects store two floats, so for every click, you get the x and y coordinates and make a new `Vector2` object. By storing them in the LinkedList, you can retrieve the points at any time in the correct order so you can connect a line.

```
LinkedList<Vector2> v = new LinkedList<Vector2>();
public void ontouch(screenX, screenY){
      v.add(new Vector2(screenX, screenY)); // add Vector2 into LinkedList
}
```

How you want to draw the lines or connect the points is up to you.

Another was is to just only keep the two most recent points that were clicked, and throw the others away. This would mean storing the lines instead of the points. If the lines are objects, then you can do this:

```
Vector2 previousPoint;
Vector2 currentPoint;
ArrayList<MyLineClass> lines = new ArrayList<MyLineClass>();
public void ontouch(screenX, screenY){
      if(previousPoint == null){
          previousPoint = new Vector2(screenX, screenY);
      }else{
          previousPoint = currentPoint;
          currentPoint = new Vector2(screenX, screenY);
          lines.add(new MyLineClass(currentPoint, previousPoint)
      }
}
```

I wrote this off the cuff but I believe this example should work.

EDIT:

Good thing LibGDX is open source. If you want to use an array of float numbers, the method simply gets an x and y coordinate in alternating order. So for each index:

0 = x1

1 = y1

2 = x2

3 = y2

4 = x3

5 = y3

etc.

It's an odd method, but I suppose it works.

Comment: the problem is that shapeRenderer.polygon(float[]); I need an array of float and not Vector2, thanks btw

Comment: I checked the LibGDX code, and I believe this is the correct answer... check the edit

Comment: I tried that too, but since I don't know how many points the user will add then I cannot initialize an array of float, float v = new float[?].

Comment: I see, I was going to suggest that you do another one of my ideas, but you already tried it in the question. What errors are you getting?